# Which NET version takes priority when running an app System or Contained App

Tags: c#, .net, version

I am working on an app for NET 5 and because NET 5 isn’t released built into windows the main suggestion I have found is to create a contained app with the NET 5 runtimes. The issue with this as I understand it is that this can lead to security issues if new releases are not made and there are issues in NET 5.

So the question is which version would take priority.

A. The App contained NET5 runtimes.

Or

B. Newer Version NET5 runtimes installed in the Windows System separately.

Answer (score 0):

For apps with self contained deployment, the only runtime version being used is the one bundled with the app itself. In that way, the apps are well isolated and side by side (3.1 apps can live nicely with 6.0 apps without breaking each other).

If you want an app to use the common runtime installed, you have to publish it with framework dependent deployment.

If your goal is to resolve vulnerabilities in self contained deployment, make sure that,

1. Your app can auto update itself
2. You publish new releases of your app whenever (likely to be monthly) Microsoft publishes a new runtime version.